# Opencart Delete Order programmatically

Tags: php, opencart, e-commerce, opencart-3

How do you delete the entire order records and it's existence in the opencart system using the order_id programmatically

Comment: Please add more details. What do you want to use PHP, SQL?

Answer (score 0):

to delete order you should delete it from this tables:

```
oc_order
oc_order_history
oc_order_option
oc_order_product
oc_order_recurring
oc_order_recurring_transaction
oc_order_shipment
oc_order_status
oc_order_total
oc_order_voucher
```

you can use this query for each table separate in your model or controller file

```
$this->db->query("DELETE FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "order WHERE order_id = '" . (int)$order_id . "'");
```

Or simply using phpMyadmin sql.